# Javascript: Is there a better shorthand for conditional variable declaration?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I have two variables `foo`& `bar` and I want to declare them based on a `condition`.

I have already shortened the code from this:

```
let foo = '';
let bar = '';

if (condition) {
  foo = 'hi';
  bar = 'bye';
} else {
  foo = 'bye';
  bar = 'hi';
}
```

To this:

```
const foo = condition ? 'hi' : 'bye';
const bar = !condition ? 'hi' : 'bye';
```

I still feel the code is repetitive with having to use ternary operator twice. Is there anyway I can shorten this code more? Thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could take a destructuring with a single condition.

```
let [foo, bar] = condition ? ['hi', 'bye'] : ['bye', 'hi'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't mind me, just trying to solve this simple problem in a complex way :)

```
let foo = 'hi';
let bar = 'bye';

[foo, bar] = !condition && [foo, bar].reverse() || [foo, bar];
```

Note: Nina Scholz's solution is perfect for your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Array destructuring as one option: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

```js
const condition = true;
const [foo, bar] = condition ? ['hi', 'bye'] : ['bye', 'hi'];

console.log({foo, bar});
```